# Calculate the module of a vector, in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

How can I calculate the module of a vector?
As a vector is not a pre-defined type in VHDL it makes sense to me that there is no function implementing the modue of a vector. If there is such I have not found it.

This is basically a problem of obtaining the square root of a number, as the module can be defined as:

> sqrt(a^2+b^2+...+n^2)

Implementing the sum of all the members of the vector squared is not a challenge so I think the most necessary part is having a function to calculate the square root of a number.

As far as I'm concerned there isn't any official package implementing this function. How to implement a function to calculate the module of a vector?

Or if you prefer it, how to implement a square root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible solution. I will provide you 3 codes.

-The first one provides the type definition used for the vector. Its not important but it is needed to make it work.

-The second one is the package in which the function is defined. It is commented so that you can easily adapt it to any kind of vector. It can probably be upgraded to make it adapt by itself using some parameters by this works fine.

-The third one is a testbench to try it out.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package tipos is
constant bandas : positive := 4;
type vector32 is array (0 to bandas-1) of signed (31 downto 0);
end package tipos;
```

Be aware of calling properly the library with the vector definition. In my case it was compiled to work for the ModelSim simulation

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
library work; use work.tipos.all;

package propios is
--function declaration.
function module (a : vector32; bands: natural) return unsigned;
end propios;   --end of package.

package body propios is  --start of package body
--definition of function
--based on: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Binary_numeral_system_.28base_2.29
function module (a : vector32; bands: natural) return unsigned is --To adapt it to a diferent number of bits in the input vector:
--substitute the 71 for the needed number. Number of bits in each element of the vector *2 + power of two that can represent the maximum
--number of bands, or fields. In this case, 32bit numbers, maximum number of bands, 256, so 2^8. 32*2+8=72.
variable sum : unsigned(71 downto 0):= (others => '0');
variable b : unsigned(71 downto 0):=(0=>'0', 70 => '1', others => '0');
variable a_unsig: unsigned(31 downto 0):=(others =>'0');--for this vector use the same length as the input vector, 32bit in my case.
variable result: unsigned (71 downto 0):= (others => '0');
begin

for i in 0 to bands-1 loop--Sum of all the elements squared
    a_unsig:=unsigned(a(i));
    sum:=sum + (a_unsig * a_unsig);
end loop;


--Square root of sum
while b>sum loop--Do any needed changes here. You only have to change the 71's
    b:='0'&'0'& b(71 downto 2);
end loop;

while (b/=0) loop
    if (sum>=result+b) then
        sum:=sum - (result + b);
        result:=('0'& result(71 downto 1))+b;
    else
        result:='0'& result(71 downto 1);
    end if;
    b:='0' & '0' & b(71 downto 2);
end loop;

return result(35 downto 0);--sqrt(2^72)=2^36. Use half of the bits you put in place of 71
end module;


end propios;  --end of the package body
```

And here is the testbench. Again take care of calling the packages properly

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
library work;
use work.propios.all;
use work.tipos.all;

ENTITY test IS 

END test;
Architecture simple of test is
signal a:vector32;
signal c: unsigned(35 downto 0);
signal b: natural:= 4;
begin
a(0)<="00000000110010011010011100000000";
a(1)<="00000000110010011010011100000000";
a(2)<="00000000110010011010011100000000";
a(3)<="00000000110010011010011100000000";


process 
begin
wait for 200ps;
c<= module (a , b);
wait;   
end process;


end simple;
```